# Official name for AD/LDAP targets

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Say I have an AD user called `flimflam` that is "located" at `OU=System, DC=fizzbuzz, DC=myorg, DC=com`:

What is the technical/appropriate verbiage for `OU=System, DC=fizzbuzz, DC=myorg, DC=com`? Location? Directory? Position? Something else?

Comment: I would still refer to that location or  container by what it is: the Organisational Unit, OU. The alternative is to ask for the Distinguished Name (DN), the full name and location of an object within the directory. I have also heard the branch in the LDAP tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items are "entries".
The "path" to an item is its *DN*, or *Distinguished Name*.
References:

[Relative article on Microsoft's MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Link from RHEL7 documentation](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat7.3/rhl-rg-en-7.3/s1-ldap-terminology.html)